# Prolog not_member dont do its job

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-dif

I have a Prolog problem here, I am trying to get **unique** airports into the list but my predicate does not work as expected.

```
not_member(C, []).
not_member(C, [H|L]) :-
   not_member(C, L),
   C \== H.

path(X, Y, [X,Y]) :-
   flight(X, Y, _, _, _, _).
path(X, Y, [X,P]) :-
   not_member(Z, P), 
   flight(X, Z, _, _, _, _),
   flight(Z, Y, _, _, _, _), 
   path(Z, Y, P).
```

Sample query with expected answers:

```
?- path(dublin, rome, L)
L = [dublin, rome] ;
L = [dublin, paris, rome] ...
```

If you need facts let me know, your help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use `dif/2` instead of `(\==)/2`. `dif/2` is a pure predicate that will work as you expect, i.e., also if some of its arguments are not yet instantiated.

Comment: I assume you mean `path(X, Y, [X|P])` not `path(X, Y, [X,P])`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the (\==)/2. The problem is that an uninstantiated P would make not_member/2 loop. So you need a predicate path/4 with four arguments:

```
:- use_module(library(basic/lists)).
path(_, X, L, _) :- member(X, L), !, fail.
path(X, X, L, [X|L]).
path(Y, X, L, R) :-
   flight(Z, X),
   path(Y, Z, [X|L], R).
```

The above predicate searches from the destination airport backwards, so that we don't need to reverse the resulting list. Here is an example database:

```
flight(zurich, frankfurt).
flight(frankfurt, zurich).
flight(zurich, munich).
flight(munich, zurich).
flight(munich, frankfurt).
flight(frankfurt, munich).
```

And here is an example run:

```
Jekejeke Prolog 2, Runtime Library 1.2.5
(c) 1985-2017, XLOG Technologies GmbH, Switzerland

?- path(zurich, frankfurt, [], L).
L = [zurich,frankfurt] ;
L = [zurich,munich,frankfurt] ;
No
```